# gparted has no installation candidate (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: dual-boot, apt, partitioning, gparted

So I'm about to partition my Ubuntu hard drive to install Windows 10 on the other half.  I go to install `gparted` to do the partitioning, and I get a `Package 'gparted' has no installation candidate` error.

Here's the full output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gparted is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gparted' has no installation candidate
```

I do `$ apt-cache search gparted` and get this returned:
`partitionmanager - file, disk and partition management for KDE`

Does this mean that my computer cannot use gparted, and I should use this instead?  What's going on here?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1320393/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @user535733 done

Comment: wow.  You're a god.  I'm curious how you knew, and how I might have screwed that up in the first place.

Comment: Explanation: The `gparted` package is in the "main" pocket of the Ubuntu Repositories. All installs include that source. If apt cannot find it, then you have a problem with your network or your sources. An `apt update` lists all your sources and tests the network, so it's an easy way to check both. Your output had no sources listed, so that was the problem. Had it listed a bunch of sources but also included a bunch of "404 Not Found" errors, that would have pointed to a networking problem. No idea how you deleted your sources. That takes talent.